# SQL query to add the number of occurrences for current year and all previous years as two numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with the following: I have a table called `Statuses` which contains two columns `period`, `status` (this is an example)

```
year Status
--------------------
2021 enrolled
2022 enrolled
2021 enrolled 
2021 temp enrolled
2023 enrolled
2023 enrolled
```

What I need is a SQL query to return the number of enrolled for 2023 and the number of enrolled for all the previous years to 2023 as one number.

So my result should looks something like this:

```
year       status
------------------
2023         2
2021-2022    3
```

Will this be possible? Apologies as I am new to SQL and not sure if I formatted this question right either.

Comment: Where is column `period` in your example data?

Answer (score 1):

We can use a union query here:

```
SELECT '2023' AS year, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE year = 2023 AND Status = 'enrolled'
UNION ALL
SELECT '< 2023', COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE year < 2023 AND Status = 'enrolled';
```

But actually, a more typical and also more performant way to do this reporting would be to use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 2023 THEN 1 END) AS [2023],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN year < 2023 THEN 1 END) AS [prior_2023]
FROM yourTable
WHERE Status = 'enrolled';
```

This approach has the advantage of only requiring a single pass over your table.

Comment: thanks the second solution works great but the result is in two columns , is there a way I can show the result in two rows like

Comment: Yes, use my first query.

Answer (score 0):

Group by max(year)(): [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33401fdbdba9d5f56a797a6a8b4a8508)

```sql
create table statuses(year int, status varchar(20));

insert into statuses(year, status)
values
(2021, 'enrolled'),
(2022, 'enrolled'),
(2021, 'enrolled'),
(2021, 'temp enrolled'),
(2023, 'enrolled'), --(2024, 'temp enrolled'),
(2023, 'enrolled');


select concat(cast(nullif(min(year), maxyear) as varchar(20))+'-', max(year)), sum(case when status = 'enrolled' then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
select *, max(year) over() as maxyear
from statuses
) as s
group by case when year = maxyear then 1 else 0 end, maxyear;

update statuses set status = 'temp enrolled';

select concat(cast(nullif(min(year), maxyear) as varchar(20))+'-', max(year)), sum(case when status = 'enrolled' then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
select *, max(year) over() as maxyear
from statuses
) as s
group by case when year = maxyear then 1 else 0 end, maxyear;
```